# Require registration before users can ask their second question?

Tags: discussion, unregistered-users

I'm pretty new to the stackexchange community and I am extremely, extremely amazed by the culture and the interface. I often see a lot of posts with the author being an unregistered user or questions that are asked by peeps with 1 rep. Many unregistered users would then get their answers without rewarding the answers. I suggest, if possible, that the authors that post the questions must then register to see the answers.

I tried to locate similar posts in meta, but couldn't narrow to the suggestion above. Prove me wrong.

**Edit**
I believe some of you have misunderstood my suggestion.  I am not saying the answers ARE not opened to any users.  I am suggesting that the person who asks the question must then register in order to ask more questions to follow up that question, which by implication, that already shows significant interests.

Comment: I agree this wasn't clear so I edited the title to make it more clear..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being able to ask questions and see answers without being registered is one of the main features of the Stack Exchange network that sets them apart from some other sites (aheum *hyphen* aheum) in the Q & A space.

So it isn't likely a suggestion like that will be implemented.

Comment: This of course went out the window here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/149052 (and IMO it was a good thing)