# Has Stack Overflow stopped its 'Question without Account' Service?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging users to create an account (and keep it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it)

I noticed today that Stack Overflow has stopped its service of putting a question without making any account. It asks the user to log in before posting question.

Any specific reason for it?

Answer (score -1):

Too many low quality questions.

See [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) blog post.

Comment: That blog post addresses a different issue.  [Yoda's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107207/has-stack-overflow-stopped-its-question-without-account-service/107209#107209) has the proper link.  I think we can expect a blog post about the new policy soon.