# Update the SO FAQ to reflect the new account requirement for asking questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, asking-questions, login

As first noted by Daniel Hilgarth [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#comment-275515), the [Do I have to log in or create an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#login) section of the Stack Overflow FAQ needs to be updated to reflect the fact that [anonymous users can no longer ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163).  As far as I can tell the regular folk can't edit this part of the FAQ, so I'd be much obliged if a dev did so.

<sub>I'm not advocating the account requirement, I'm merely advocating FAQtual accuracy :)</sub>

Comment: Excellent.  We've needed this for a long time.

Comment: I would love to spend a couple of seconds, but I'm not sure if I can be considered a credible and/or official source. I'll upvote instead ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done, thanks for the reminder, new text is:

```
    <p>
        You can answer and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much
        like <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a>. There are some
        things you won&rsquo;t be able to do on the site without registering, such as vote or ask new questions.
        But it&rsquo;s <a href="/users/login">easy to register</a>.
    </p>
```