# You must log in to ask a question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging users to create an account (and keep it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it)

Is this now a feature - you can only ask a question if you signup for an account?

Are anonymous user questions now banned on SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the FAQ:

[Do I have to login?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#login)

Hope that helps!

Comment: You didn't used to have to. In fact it was one of the original principles of not becoming 'the hyphen site' that you didn't have to signup!

Comment: Does my response answer your question?

Comment: yes I didn't know if you knew it was a new feature since you are a new member!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a [new policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163).