# How to regain access to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts

I cannot access Stack Overflow because they have put a trick on my IP address. It does not refuse my access, but it asks me to log in again and again if I want to ask a question. My browser accepts cookies.

I know I haven't done anything wrong with my account so I don't feel guilty, but at the same time I can understand that there are policies to exclude some users that write bad or not-so-beautiful questions.

Now, I want to regain my access because I need information about programming issues. What have I to do?

- 1 - I open a new private chrome session
- 2 - Login with Stack Exchange: email address and password
- 3 - Welcome P5music with 76 points
- 4 - Ask question button
- 5 - You must login

Comment: Is there a *reason* you believe login issues are a result of a "trick"?

Comment: Your [Stack Overflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/930835/) is unregistered. Register the account to be able to ask questions.

Comment: I already registered, now if I click on register it recognizes me and doesn't allow to ask questions because it starts again and again

Comment: It would help if you actually tell us what's happening. What error are you getting?

Comment: if I logout and then login simply it does not even ask my username and password but welcomes me and if I click on "Ask question" button it ask me to login again. I can see my username and 76 points which are the points in my registered account not the cookied one. I cannot register now too, but I already registered.

Comment: I don't want to offend you, but this very question might be a good start to learn [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). We need many more details to understand what is going on! Also please merge your comments into your question, but with more details too. (Like: what message do you get when trying to register again? What does "it recognizes me" mean? Surely the site [thinks you're still unregistered](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RgpLX.png)!)

Comment: Oh, and @Chris [is right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107163/84237).

Comment: 1 - I open a new private chrome session 2 - login with stackexchange: email address and password 3 - welcome P5music with 76 points 4 - ask question button - 5 you must login

Comment: How about moving your responses such as the above into the question.

Comment: is your browser accepting cookies? I had some similar problem because my browser rejected them...

Comment: There's indeed something weird here... Checking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure yet what happened here; we'll investigate that. For some reason, you were considered an unregistered user, even though you had a valid OpenId (and you had accounts on other sites). We'll have a closer look at that.

Anyway, I've updated your data; you're now a registered user, and should be able to ask questions again.

Sorry about that.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same situation, but someone in chat was [having similar-sounding issues](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1878726#1878726) the other day.

Comment: And another user [is also complaining](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116267/why-did-not-i-post-any-question-though-i-logged-in-successfully) *"when I ask for question it was redirect me to login page"*.

Comment: Thanks @Arjan; yep, same issue.