# I am logged in, but when trying to ask a question I need to log in again

Tags: support, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to regain access to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/how-to-regain-access-to-stack-overflow)

Why can I not post any question on Stack Overflow?

I have logged in successfully, and I am a registered user. But when I try to ask a question, it redirects me to the login page instead.

Comment: ^^^This is a question you posted.

Comment: Providing a LITTLE bit more information might help...

Comment: As per your comment *"actually when I ask for question it was redirect me to login page"*, this might be related to [How to regain access to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/how-to-regain-access-to-stack-overflow/113530#113530) (see balpha's answer there).

Comment: Are you [sure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RUnMp.png) you're a registered user? (If you're not, [go here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account).)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking at the wrong site, as on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900481/moin) your reputation is 11, and you asked 4 questions.
This is Meta Stack Overflow, a different site, and here you asked just this question.

Anyway, you don't have a registered account on Stack Overflow, as the account reports "unregistered account"; this means that your account is a temporary account that exists until a cookie set on your browser exists. If you would use another browser, or another computer, your account would not be recognized.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: But if this is not a registered account, then *"I logged in successfully"* makes no sense. My bet is on [the issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/how-to-regain-access-to-stack-overflow/113530#113530) I linked to in my comment. (Oh, balpha just confirmed that.)

Comment: That is what the account associated with his account on MSO said.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue as [How to regain access to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/how-to-regain-access-to-stack-overflow/), we still haven't gotten to the bottom of that. I've fixed your data, you should be able to ask now. Apologies for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your page, press the button on the right that says main. This should take you to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). I'm assuming this is where you meant to post your question, so check your profile on this website to see if you did.

Also when you go to submit your answer, make sure that the answer actually was submitted. Sometimes when you submit, it will reload the page and tell you that you need to give more information, need to provide at least 1 tag, etc... So you may have thought you submitted a question, but you never met the website's question standards, so it wasn't submitted.

Comment: nope actually when I ask for question it was redirect me to login page.

Comment: Mmm fix english grammar, you must. Also, could you provide a series of screenshots to show what you mean? Take the screenshots, edit your answer, and hopefully I'll be able to help you more with that information