# Partial protect question hover text is irrelevant

Tags: discussion, wording

When hovering over the "protect" link underneath a question (15k+ users), the `title` text reads:

> disallow answers by anonymous and very new low rep users

Isn't the anonymous users part irrelevant, as users must sign up to post on the site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you have to sign up to *ask questions* on Stack Overflow.

Unregistered users are [still allowed to *answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163) them (unless protected, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Users must [sign up to post *questions*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163), but they can still post answers (to any question).