# When/why did Stack Overflow disallow anonymous questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history, anonymous-visitors

I remember a time when anonymous users could post questions without an account on Stack Overflow. [IIRC](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIRC), this is no longer possible.

I don't mind the removal. I DO, however, find it interesting that it was built and then removed. What was the rationale? Are there any blog posts talking about it? Are there any stories from the trenches that lead to the decision?

Why did Stack Overflow drop anonymous content?

I ask because I'm faced with a similar situation and tested wisdom is interesting.

(Again, I don't want this to be a feature debate, but rather a historical recounting).

Comment: I don't know the date, but it was quite some time ago.  Like several years.

Comment: I think the anonymous questions will be pretty much needed in case [this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43735/sex-games-toys?referrer=I6pSkOidRNuRUmuJ6LxS8Q2) gets launched ;-)

Comment: If it is true that you can no longer ask questions without bothering to register, they really should stop advertising this on the [about page](http://stackexchange.com/about): *"...you can ask or answer questions without even bothering to register."*

Comment: @Asad log out and try, doesn't appear possible. Right?

Comment: @Asad: Stack Overflow is the only exception in the SE Network, AFAIK.

Comment: @Robert: [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/what-can-we-do-about-extremely-low-quality-questions-from-unregistered-users/4001#4001)

Answer (score 11):

When: September, 2011

Why: With a question volume of between 4,000 and 5,000 questions per day, it no longer "made sense"

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163)

---

[Programmers (now Software Engineering) followed suit a year later](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/what-can-we-do-about-extremely-low-quality-questions-from-unregistered-users/4001#4001)

Answer (score 5):

The SE platform optimizes for high-quality answers; for that, the starting point is high-quality questions.  See [Optimizing for Pearls, not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).  Note that posting an answer is still almost frictionless; anyone can post an answer to a question, even anonymously.

To that end, requiring registration became part of a [comprehensive effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56817/102937) to combat a flood of low-quality questions that were plaguing Stack Overflow in late 2011.

**See Also**
[Clarify the "No registration required" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120707/102937)
[Encouraging users to create an account (and keep it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107152/102937)