# Update about page to reflect that questions can't be asked without registering (on Stack Overflow)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, unregistered-users, tour

> **Related: [Clarify the "No registration required" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120707/200500)**

Evidently [it is no longer possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/200500) to ask questions on Stack Overflow without signing up for an account. I have no opinions on this either way, but I do think the following section in [the network about page](https://stackexchange.com/about) needs to be changed:

> The sites are free and open to everyone – **you can *ask* or answer
> questions without even bothering to register**. Better yet, you have
> access to the full archive of existing questions and answers – again,
> without needing to give up so much as an email address.

Either that part should be moved to the about page of sites where this is true, or there should be a footnote or something that states Stack Overflow is an exception. I am not sure if there are other places where this needs to be updated as well.

Additionally, the ["why register?" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register) on Stack Overflow reads as following:

> Registration is not required to participate on Stack Exchange; you can
> read, answer, and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much like on
> Wikipedia. **There are some things you won’t be able to do on the site
> without registering, however, such as vote**. Registering is easy, and
> once logged in, you can gain other key privileges by earning
> reputation.

This should also be updated to explicitly mention asking questions (a somewhat major feature) as being a thing unregistered users can't do.

Comment: The registering thing is only for SO (and possible SU/SF), I don't think it is mandatory on the whole network.

Comment: @Mat Yes, but that is one of their flagship websites. Advertise the feature where it is available, don't make a blanket claim with unmentioned exceptions.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the related question?

Comment: @JanDvorak No. That one asks for the "no registration required" statement (which is technically correct, just sort of misleading) on the sidebar of the main page to be changed. I'm asking for the about page (which has a false claim) to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as neither of the two pages you link to have the information you mentioned any more (for a while now, you question was probably overlooked).