# Remove the unnecessary middle step for unregistered users to ask a question on SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Ok so I am a **new user** on Stack Overflow and I want to ask my **first Question** (*yay*).

### Step 1 (one):

*ok* So I click on <kbd>Ask Question</kbd>:

[image: ask it]

### Step 2 (two):

*Read Read Read* Now I have a whole [megillah](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/megillah) to read:

[image: reading...]
**Now** I click proceed to get to the next step! Finally asking my question! :-)

### Step 3 (three):

I am stopped **dead** in my tracks and am asked to log in:
[image: log me in!]

Why was that second step necessary?
Should that not be asked to log in **before** I have to read that whole thing?

This could deter a new user or two.

I suggest only showing the "**How to Ask**" page if a user is **already** logged in and tries to ask a new question, not beforehand.

Comment: The cake is a lie!

Comment: So you're actually advocating that ***less people*** read the instructions on how to ask than they do now?

Comment: @RobertHarvey See my comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124008/remove-the-unnecessary-middle-step-for-unregistered-users-to-ask-a-question-on-s#comment331224_124009

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I thought there was no requirement to register/login in order to ask questions. When did that change?

Comment: @Oded a little while back. looking for reference now....

Comment: `This could deter a new user or two.` -- Mission accomplished.  If you can't get through one page of text, you probably won't be capable of asking a decent question.

Comment: @Oded I cannot find the reference at the moment.

Comment: +1 for the Yiddish.  Do you suggest swapping step 2 and step 3?

Comment: @JonEricson hehe thats **not** yiddish, its hebrew :-P. I guess, basically that **is** what I mean.

Comment: @Oded: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152

Comment: @RobertHarvey ahhh there you go ^_^

Comment: Oh.  In the definition, I saw: "Origin: 
1950–55;  < Yiddish megile  literally, scroll < Hebrew məgillāh".  Still, I like picking up interesting new words.  ;-)

Comment: @Robert: [Users don't read _anything_.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html)  I'm pretty sure the average person confronted with that page will treat it like any other legalese form required to do anything on so many sites these days.  It looks vaguely like an EULA that we've all been trained to ignore.

Comment: @JonEricson: I thought a məgillāh was a type of gorilla.

Comment: @Won't haha oy.... (like my numbers? ^_^)

Comment: @Oded The [list of recent feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) reports, "2011-09-23: You must be a [registered user to ask questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163) on Stack Overflow. Unregistered users may still answer questions however."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making your case exactly backwards: step #2 deters almost nobody.  [Here's why](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/10/treating-user-myopia.html):

> The plain fact is **users will not read *anything* you put on the screen.**

If I'd been confronted with the megillah (it's going to go into my vocabulary now!), I'd skip all the nonsense about "How to Ask" (no offense to whoever wrote it) and find that sweet, sweet checkbox so that I could get on with asking my question.

The 0.0001% of new users who do take the time to read the text are also the folks who will follow all the rules (and then some) spelled out in the megillah anyway.

By the way, a checkbox just screams [EULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) to anyone who has used the internet lately.

Comment: The checkbox should probably be buried in the middle.  Or maybe hide it, and put a "Click this link to show the Accept checkbox so that you may escape from this megillah" right in the bottom 3/4ths.  That way, when people come to Meta asking "How do I get past the How to Ask screen" we can maliciously close it as a dupe and laugh at them in the comments.

Comment: @Won't You are truly an evil genius ahead of your time.

Comment: That's really evil ;)

Answer (score 2):

It sure seems like you could simplify that a and still leave the wall of text there.

Just change the **proceed »** link to something like **proceed to login » (Logins are required)** or something like that.  Only allow users to click the link after the checkbox is selected.  Having an additional page doesn't really seem to add anything useful.

[image: logins are required]